# How to write Python WSGI application that displays both text and image on a web page

Tags: python, wsgi

I have seen simple wsgi applications that display either `Hello World` or a PNG image (but not both) on a web page.

The first page uses `'Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'` and the second uses `'content-type', 'image/png'`.

How do I write a simple application (using say `wsgiref.simple_server.make_server`) that sends BOTH `text/html` and `image/png` on the SAME web page?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if I understand it all correctly, you can not. Your HTML code will need to have an `<img src="path/url/to/image.png">` in it and that path will need to be either served as a static image or be a second request to the same WSGI server that will give you a png raw with a proper `Content-type`.

So, let me elaborate.

Say, you have a request path of http://server.com/mypage that will return you an HTML with `Content-type` set to `text/html` and within that HTML you will have:

```
<img src="http://server.com/myimage">
```

Then, in your WSGI app you implement two routes:

1. `/mypage` that gives you an HTML back
2. `/myimage` that gives you back a PNG image

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate for a second... while you can't have a web page that has both text/html and image/png on the same web page, you could send a text/html response that has an inline css style that has a base64 encoded representation of a PNG within the HTML using the Data URI Scheme.

Comment: Oh my :) I suppose that's a very creative implementation that will work, I wouldn't think of that off-hand. But I'm not sure anyone would want that as a standard implementation and not as an academic exercise .

Comment: Actually, it's very useful in production. Many people i know have build/deploy scripts that stick smaller, often used, images into the CSS using Data URI to streamline content delivery and caching.  It can save a few requests that wouldn't necessarily be on the same server to benefit from a keepalive connection, and add up to additional billing on CDNs.  BUT... It's totally an academic hack in the context of this use case scenario.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks for the information, didn't know that!

Comment: Look into it!  It can be a great strategy.  Here's a good primer of positives - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819314/why-use-data-uri-scheme

Comment: Thank you all, I need a little bit more study and time to understand these suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
from wsgiref.util import setup_testing_defaults
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

def simple_app(environ, start_response):
  setup_testing_defaults(environ)
  path    = str( environ['PATH_INFO']
  headers = [('Server', 'Apache'),('Content-type', 'text/html')]
  rsp     = 'oops'

  if '.html' in path:
  rsp  = some_html

  if '.png' in path:
     headers = [('Server', 'Apache'),('Content-type', 'image/png')]
     rsp = some_png

  start_response(status, headers)
  return rsp

httpd = make_server('', 8008, simple_app)
print "Serving on port 8000..."
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Please note that the question specifically says `How to write` and not `provide me with a`  so this is not very helpful.  Please add more description about _why_ or _how_ it works instead of just providing it.