# Angular image upload

Tags: angular, file-upload

I am trying to use `ngx-image-cropper` to upload images on my application, but I cannot save the cropped image. For example, if I try to save the main file (the file which is loaded through the `input type="file"`), everything works fine. In this case, the file is sent like this:

```
{name: "300_3.jpg", 
lastModified: 1510510128437, 
lastModifiedDate: Sun Nov 12 2017 20:08:48 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", 
size: 81972, …}
```

But if I try to upload the cropped version of the image, the file looks like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU............
```

And the response from the server is something like:

```
{error: "Bad Request",
exception:"org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException",
message: "Required request part 'file' is not present",
path: "/api/myEndPoint/",
status: 400,
timestamp: 1518424822285}
```

So basically I need to send an abject as in the first case, but all I have is a base64 item.

Here is also the HTML code, in case it helps:

```
<image-cropper
                    [imageChangedEvent]="imageChangedEvent"
                    [maintainAspectRatio]="true"
                    [aspectRatio]="4 / 4"
                    [resizeToWidth]="250"
                    format="png"
                    (imageCropped)="imageCropped($event)"
                    (imageLoaded)="imageLoaded()"
                    (loadImageFailed)="loadImageFailed()"
                    *ngIf="isUploadedFile">
                </image-cropper>
```

Can someone please advise how may I upload the cropped version and not the initial file I uploaded? Or is this something which needs to be fixed on the server, so it can accept the file I sent?
Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to convert your base64 data to multipart:  See here if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That string:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU............
```

means that you have your cropped image as `dataURI`. If you want to bring your upload of cropped image to work, then you should convert it from `dataURI` to `Blob`. If you have done this, then you can create from `Blob` an `File` and upload this to server.

Here is a function for converting `dataURI` to `Blob`:

```
  dataURItoBlob(dataURI): Blob {
    const byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    const mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
    const ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    let ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([ab], { type: mimeString });
  }
```

And now you can create `File` and upload it to server. Here is an example of uplaod function:

```
  uploadAttachmentToServer() {
    const fileToUpload: File = new File([this.dataURItoBlob(yourCroppedImage)], 'filename.png');
    this.attachmentService.postAttachment(fileToUpload).subscribe(data => {
      // success, do something
    }, error => {
      // failure, do something
    });
  }
```

Comment: Also consider the use of dataURI, if possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6819412/1235935

Answer (score 2):

Actually [ngx-image-cropper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper) provides an attribute `imageCroppedFile` which gives you the cropped image as converted to `Blob`, for example in your html:

```
<image-cropper
                [imageChangedEvent]="imageChangedEvent"
                ...
                (imageCroppedFile)="fileCropped($event)">
</image-cropper>
```

then in your component you can convert from `Blob` to `File`:

```
fileCropped(blob: Blob) {
    const file = new File([blob], 'image.png');
    // upload the file
}
```

Comment: using version 3.1.9 and can't see "imageCroppedFile"

Answer (score 0):

The ngx-image-cropper comes with a base64ToFile function which returns a Blob object.

```
import { ImageCropperedEvent, base64Tofile } from 'ngx-image-cropper'
```

and your code should look like:

```
someFunction(): File {
  // Assuming you have stored the event.base64 in an instance variable 'croppedImage'
  const file: File = new File([base64ToFile(this.croppedImage)], 'fileName.png');
  return file;
}
```