# Getting img src with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am currently learning jquery and in one of my activities I have to get the src from some images on [this](http://www.sensacine.com/) webpage. But I can't seem to get the img URL. 
I managed selecting the image and to get any attribute but not src's url.
This is the selector i am using:

```
$('img.thumbnail-img').attr("src");
```

But it gives me this back instead of the url:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAwAEAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAADAAQAAAIDhI9WADs=
```

EDIT:
Hi! I think i didnt't quite explain myself. I want to get the image src url, and instead i get what i pasted above. By looking at the html of the page you can see that there is an actual image url like [this one](http://es.web.img3.acsta.net/c_150_200/pictures/18/02/21/10/05/2137559.jpg) for example, but instead i get that data:image... thing which, by following the steps in the solution, is not the image i want to get. 
Maybe the selector is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: That is a URL ~ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use data URI scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819314/why-use-data-uri-scheme)

Answer (score 1):

The image used there is not on a file, it's an encoded base64 image. Therefore you get the image instead of URL.

You try this:

1. Open https://www.base64decode.org/
2. Paste `R0lGODlhAwAEAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAADAAQAAAIDhI9WADs=` inside the textbox
3. Click **DECODE**
4. It should download the encoded image as a GIF file to your computer.

Comment: You could even just paste the data-uri into your browser location bar

Comment: I didn't know that, let me try it :)

Comment: It's a 3x4 px transparent gif so kinda hard to see :)

Comment: Yep same results. Thanks for letting me know that!

Answer (score -1):

I'll answer myself here, just solved it.

The problem was that, for some reason, in this webpage the attribute for the real image url was "data-src" so, i changed that in the selector and everything worked.

Thanks everyone for the help!